# How to train a stray cat where I will feed it?

Tags: cats, training, strays

For several months we have a stray cat visiting our house regularly. She was pregnant, and has given birth to 4 adorable kittens on our roof.

When she was pregnant, we had forbidden her from entering the house by:

1. picking up and put her outside (mostly done by me)
2. scare her when she approached the door (mostly done by my parents)
3. shut the door right when we see her approach the door

We fed her every few days, but now we don't. However, rarely we still give some leftover (meat or bones) on outside of our terrace. We fed her on the same regular spot.

However, after her giving birth, we allowed her to wander around the house in hope she will move the kittens to our house (not on the roof). Combined with current lack of feeding, this result on her sniffing around the kitchen and stealing chicken meat from our kitchen.

How to solve this problem? How can we establish that we won't feed her outside the regular spot, and we will only do it (maybe) twice a week?

Answer (score 4):

A cat with newborns needs more food than a pregnant cat. So she will be even more hungry that when she was pregnant.

You cannot establish a pattern with the cat that you will only feed her twice a week. The cat is hungry and has no notion of waiting several days between feeds.

Also a cat has no understanding of stealing food, she's trying to scavenge food from wherever she can.

It's unlikely she will bring her kittens down from the roof and bring them into your home, especially not if you've shooed her away. She has put them up there to protect them from predators.

If you want to bring the kittens into your home, the best thing will be to actually climb onto the roof and bring them down yourselves. Put them in a box with a towel - to keep them together and feeling safe. Place some food in a bowl beside the box - perhaps in the kitchen, where the mum is used to finding food.

From there will you need to put them in a room with a kitty litter and feed the mother several times a day and keep her with fresh water, as she may take the kittens back out of the house.

If your family cannot commit to caring for this cat and her kittens, contact an [animal welfare organisation locally to you](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=cat%20welfare%20java%20indonesia&oq=cat%20welfare%20java%20indonesia&aqs=chrome..69i57.4443j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The mother will need to be desexed and so will the kittens, otherwise the epidemic of strays will continue.

From [Australia Asks “Who’s For Cats?”](http://www.australiananimalwelfare.com.au/app/webroot/files/upload/files/Australia%20asks%20%27Who%27s%20for%20cats%27.pdf) by 
Carole Webb

> An estimation from
>   a USA study cites that in 7 years, a female cat and her young can produce 420,000
>   cats.